# Powershell : How to check the good execution of a batch file on a remote computer using invoke-command

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, error-code

here is the relevant code :

```
$op=invoke-command -computername test -scriptblock{
        & "cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\psbatch.bat 2>&1 
        $LASTEXITCODE 
    }
if ($op - eq 0) {echo "success"}
else {echo "failure"}
```

The problem is that if my batch echo something, the output will be capture in $op so it will not be equal to 0.

How to handle that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$op=invoke-command -computername test -scriptblock{
    & "cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\psbatch.bat 2>&1 
    $LASTEXITCODE 
}
if (@($op)[-1] -eq 0) {echo "success"}
else {echo "failure"}
```

Force the result to an array, and then test just the last line, which will be the last exit code.  Anything echoed before that will be ignored.